# Как добавить условие в SQL запрос?

Tags: sql

Запрос выводит новые видео

```
SELECT A.*,B.UID,B.username 
FROM video A, signup B 
WHERE A.UID=B.UID AND A.active ='1' AND A.channel IN ('9') 
ORDER BY A.VID desc LIMIT 10
```

есть условие, которое выводит восстановленные видео

`restored='yes' AND active_date = CURDATE()`

как их совместить в одном запросе, чтобы выводились и новые и восстановленные видео?

Comment: (1 условие) OR (2 условие)

Comment: Видимо так: `A.restored='yes' OR A.active='1'`.

Comment: вам бы еще `from a, b` переписать на `from a join b`

Comment: А можете написать полный запрос? Что-то у меня не выходит, отдельные запросы работают, а совместный зависает.